# Copying files to nonexisting directories in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a programm that copies fotos and renames them according to their date, and I want to automatically copy a foto to a given subfolder, i.e. something like "\...\2014-09-28\13:34.jpg". Copying to existing folders works great, but at least shutils copy2 command doesn't seem to be capable of creating those nonexisting subfolders on the fly, i.e. it raises

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Roman\Desktop\Foddos!\Tmp\2010-03\13 (0).jpg'

(note that the 2010-13 subfolder doesn't exist) Is there any method that does?

PS: The whole procedure worked well with os.rename. But I don't want to move my files (and copying them to a temp directory and than using rename seems to be a pretty nasty workaround)

PPS: I'm using Python 2.7.6 on windows 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple solution is to check first if the directory exists with `os.path.isdir`, if not create it.

```
if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(parent, subdir)):
   os.mkdir(os.path.join(parent, subdir))

# Your normal method here
```

You can also use `os.makedirs` to create any intermediate directories, but note that this method will raise an exception if any of the directories already exist:

> Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all
>   intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.
>   Raises an error exception if the leaf directory already exists or
>   cannot be created. The default mode is 0777 (octal). On some systems,
>   mode is ignored. Where it is used, the current umask value is first
>   masked out.